# Restore built in javascript functions

Tags: javascript, browser

Is this possible?

Very much in need of the `window.scrollTo()` function, but it seems that sites like Facebook and others have removed them (or at least removed the references).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have not removed them. It does matter when you call them though.

Since most content if FB is brought in the page by ajax, if you call the scroll before the content is fetched, there is nowhere to scroll..

If you open firebug (*or whatever javascript console you use*) and issue a window.scrollTo(0,1000) while a page is displayed, it will scroll just fine. So it is there.

So be more specific about what you are trying to do, so we can see if we can help.

---

***update after comment***

For orkut specifically: They have created a wrapper `div` of the whole content that is 100% width and height. So the window does not have any room to scroll, as all content is isnide the wrapped and the scroll happens there. So the `window.scrollTo` does nothing (*it exists though*).

To actually scroll in there you need to find the container `div` which is the parent of the one with id `gwtPanel` and use its `scrollTop` property.

```
var scrollingNode = document.getElementById('gwtPanel').parentNode;
scrollingNode.scrollTop=500;
```

Comment: Its on a facebook like clone called Orkut (produced by google). Calling the function from the firebug console gives me an "undefined" and has no affect. Even though now I realized that the function was returning "undefined" but was actually defined. There are no iframes on the page I tested this on.